# @media queries with Akamai causing MySQL queries?

Tags: 7, theming, cdn

I hope someone can help me answer this question.

I'm developing a responsive site in Drupal 7 with the Omega framework and hope to use Akamai as a CDN. The whole site will be statically cached and serve 99.9% anonymous users.

However, someone told me that when a cached, anonymous user triggers an @media css query event during a screen re-size, it will cause Drupal to not cache properly in Akamai, and fire off a new MySQL query on every resize.

Is there any truth to this? Has anyone ever experienced anything like this? It doesn't make any sense to me ... I have not been able to test it out, primarily because I don't have Akamai yet. Any help regarding this rumor is appreciated.

Thanks!